# Missing geombars ggplot2

Tags: geom-bar

I am using ggplot2 to plot SPI values. However, i have noticed that there are some missing values in the plot which is visible as gaps. I have checked my data and it is correct.

How to clear the missing values in the plot?

My SPI Plot using ggplot2

[image]

My code

```
ggplot(df)+
  geom_bar(aes(x=tperiod, y=SPI_rrP, fill=sign), stat = "identity")+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("pos"="darkblue","neg"="red"))+
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-4,4), breaks = seq(-4, 4, 0.5))+
  scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0), breaks=seq(1971,2020,4))+
  labs(y="Plaisance RR Station (SPI-12)", x="Month/Year")+
  theme(axis.title = element_text(face="bold.italic", size=8),
        axis.title.y =element_text(face="bold.italic", size=8),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size=8,color = "#000000",hjust=0.6),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size=8, color="#000000"),
        axis.line = element_line(size=0.2,color="#000000"),
        plot.title = element_text(vjust=-10,hjust=0.01,size=10),
        legend.position = "none")
```

[My data link via google drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wGR72WPmMh8rPmaZKVm3gPJu9YfdLNMA/view?usp=drive_link)

Comment: First of all, the data in your google drive is protected so we can't access it. You can try using `dput()` on your data and adding that to your question so we can try to replicate.

Comment: It's possible that your plot is correct and there aren't actually missing values or "gaps" in your graph. I've noticed sometimes that ggplot will display gaps despite having values for every interval on my x-axis. I'm not sure if this a known issue, but I think it comes down to ggplot's pixelation/rendering of the image. whenever I've saved the plot using `ggsave` the gaps disappear. You could also try playing with `width = 1` to your `geom_bar()` command.